SQL search for a string/numeric format in a where clause
I'm using SQLite3 for my testing. I'm trying to implement a search format mask in a where clause to clean up some freeform text held in a database.
Is it possible to extract four numbers followed by a dash and then five numbers eg. xxxx-xxxxx
Here are some of the variations of data I have:
'Widget 1234-12345 Blah Blah',
'1234-12345_A',
'1234-12345 and 6789-12345'
'1234-1234567'

All of the above should return '1234-12345' as it's the first value that would meet our numeric mast of xxxx-xxxxx

SQLite supports Regex for Select-Querys with the following syntax:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute REGEXP '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}';

The Regex
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}

will give you 4 digits followed by dash followed by 5 digits.
If you want to match not only the digits but also the stuff around it change the Regex to
.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}.*

It will give you all leading and trailing characters of any form.
